# Can't add a secondary Facebook email because it's "owned by a disabled account"

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to change my Facebook email, by first adding a secondary email to my account and then make it as primary, but I can't seem to do it because "The account that owns the email address you entered has been disabled.".

I've never had 2 Facebook accounts, I believe the other account was rightfully disabled, but it's definitely not mine, and somehow it has my email address associated with it.

I've searched emails received from Facebook in my inbox, and indeed I've received 4 emails:

- 29/09/2016: "Just one more step to get started on Facebook"
- 30/09/2016: "Welcome back to Facebook"
- 30/09/2016: "Just one more step to get started on Facebook"
- 04/10/2016: "Reminder: Confirm your Facebook account"

Those emails handfully include a "report" link in their footer, but using them now doesn't work because they are expired... I don't remember whether I clicked on them at the time (probably not, because I wouldn't have receive 4 emails otherwise).

When using the Facebook "forgot password" link and entering the mentioned email it says there is no account associated (well, if it's disabled they're probably right).

What are my options to add this email to my Facebook account?

[edit February 2024] I finally found a way. Facebook support is useless. I had an Instagram account linked to the email I wanted to connect. And in what seems to be a new "Accounts Center" page on Facebook, I was able to link my Instagram email to my Facebook account. Yipee!

Comment: For anyone struggling to find forms sometime in the future, https://www.postplanner.com/how-to-contact-facebook-to-get-support/ seems to be a useful resource right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Facebook disable any account, then explain the reason (most of the time) for disabling the account to the user. You directly cannot use an email which was associated with a disabled account. Use this following link and send your concern to Facebook:
[Email address already in use](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=255904741169641).

If they find your explanation valid, might you be able to use your email address.

Learn more about [Disabled Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/185747581553788/).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the link to this form. I could only find the "complain form for disabled accounts"! Much appreciated :)

Comment: The first link is broken